# OpenAPI (Swagger) specification for bulk endpoints

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4.4, webapi, swagger, bulk

We are integrating with a Magento webshop via its REST API. We are generating a client based on the OpenAPI (Swagger) specification (via `/rest/schema`).

Now, we want to use the [bulk api](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/). However, these endpoints don't seem to be in the OpenAPI specification, and as a result we cannot use the generated client to use these bulk API endpoints.

Any idea on how to the get the OpenAPI specification for bulk API endpoints?

Comment: If I understand your question, you use the SmartBear swagger and you might have looked at the async for for it. But somehow you are not seeing the API endpoints that relate to bulk operations?

Comment: Indeed: the Swagger specification that Magento provides does not contain the bulk endpoints, such as `POST /rest/async/bulk/V1/products`.

Comment: May I ask if you are using community or enterprise? and which version?

Comment: Enterprise (Adobe Commerce). Version 2.4.4.